# How to share the network between the several demesions in the data in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, encoding, pytorch, conv-neural-network

let’s take my input as X in shape ( N, C, T, V). N is batch size, C is channels, T frames, V points. So if I need to encode a single for a given channel c1 for a given point v1 using a 1D conv network, i have to select X[:,c1,T,v1]. Lets assume that the 1D network is shared and to encoder the signals for every point and every channel i have to use for loops as

```
class EnCo1D(nn.Conv1d):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(EnCo1D, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      def forward(self, x, squeeze=False):
          # x: N x C x L
          if x.dim() not in [2, 3]:
             raise RuntimeError("{} accept 2/3D tensor as input".format(self.__name__))
          x = super().forward(x if x.dim() == 3 else torch.unsqueeze(x, 1))
          if squeeze:
             x = torch.squeeze(x)
      return x

for channel in range (0,x.shape[1]):
    for points  in range (0,x.shape[3]):
        s = EnCo1D(x[:,channel ,:,points ])
```

Here the network is an encoding network which has a 1D conv blocks. Although my target is accomplished I felt that the code I used is not optimised. So can you help me to implement this one in a much more professional manner ?